# HttpWebRequest using Basic authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, credentials, webrequest

I'm trying to go through an authentication request that mimics the "basic auth request" we're used to seeing when setting up IIS for this behavior.

The URL is: https://telematicoprova.agenziadogane.it/TelematicoServiziDiUtilitaWeb/ServiziDiUtilitaAutServlet?UC=22&SC=1&ST=2
(warning: https!)

This server is running under UNIX and Java as application server.

This is the code I use to connect to this server:

```
CookieContainer myContainer = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://telematicoprova.agenziadogane.it/TelematicoServiziDiUtilitaWeb/ServiziDiUtilitaAutServlet?UC=22&SC=1&ST=2");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(xxx,xxx);
request.CookieContainer = myContainer;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

(I copied this from another post on this site). But I receive this answer from the server:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send.

I think I tried every possible task my knowledge on C# has to offer me, but nothing...

Comment: I think this one would have worked if you had added:

request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Answer (score 366):

You can also just add the authorization header yourself.

Just make the name "Authorization" and the value "Basic BASE64({USERNAME:PASSWORD})"

```
var username   = "abc";
var password   = "123";
string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
                               .GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

### Edit

Switched the encoding from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1 per [What encoding should I use for HTTP Basic Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242316/what-encoding-should-i-use-for-http-basic-authentication) and Jeroen's comment.

Comment: So how do you know for sure that UTF8 is the right encoding to use?

Comment: Nice catch.  It looks like the request Authentication header should be encoded in ISO-8859-1.  Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242316/what-encoding-should-i-use-for-http-basic-authentication

Comment: Aaaargh! 1: Thanks, mate. 2. I'd really like to understand why the other methods, setting the authentication method in the CredentialCache, wouldn't work at all. They are supposed to, aren't they?

Comment: All the msdn documentation points to yes, the other methods should work.  However, I've never been able to get them to work.

Comment: Not working for me (neither utf-8 nor ISO-8859-1). Any suggestions what to check ?    It works when I do " webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserID, Password);" .

Comment: Worked for me. I was getting 401 (Unauthorized) using code similar to that in the question.

Answer (score 70):

I finally got it!

```
string url = @"https://telematicoprova.agenziadogane.it/TelematicoServiziDiUtilitaWeb/ServiziDiUtilitaAutServlet?UC=22&SC=1&ST=2";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = GetCredential();
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

and this is `GetCredential()`

```
private CredentialCache GetCredential()
{
    string url = @"https://telematicoprova.agenziadogane.it/TelematicoServiziDiUtilitaWeb/ServiziDiUtilitaAutServlet?UC=22&SC=1&ST=2";
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
    CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ead_username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ead_password"]));
    return credentialCache;
}
```

YAY!

Answer (score 35):

If you can use the `WebClient` class, using basic authentication becomes simple:

```
var client = new WebClient {Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user_name", "password")};
var response = client.DownloadString("https://telematicoprova.agenziadogane.it/TelematicoServiziDiUtilitaWeb/ServiziDiUtilitaAutServlet?UC=22&SC=1&ST=2");
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
System.Net.CredentialCache credentialCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache(); 
credentialCache.Add(
    new System.Uri("http://www.yoururl.com/"),
    "Basic", 
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
);

...
...

httpWebRequest.Credentials = credentialCache;
```

Comment: Is it definately basic auth?  Also, can you access the resource with your username/password via a browser?

Comment: It seems to be a basic auth over https. If you click on the link i provided, the browser pop ups the username/password" request as the same do when you do "basic auth" on IIS or using a .htaccss file on a folder via apache. I tried to use fiddler but i have no clue about.

Comment: i just learned that the website is running under IBM http server. This can be a helpful news?

Answer (score 8):

For those using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), it might fail when using [SimpleAuthenticator](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Authenticators/SimpleAuthenticator.cs) (possibly due to not using ISO-8859-1 behind the scene). I managed to get it done by explicitly sending Basic Authentication headers:

```
string username = "...";
string password = "...";

public IRestResponse GetResponse(string url, Method method = Method.GET)
{
    string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
    var client = new RestClient(url);
    var request = new RestRequest(method );
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {encoded}");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    return response;
}

var response = GetResponse(url);
txtResult.Text = response.Content;
```

Answer (score 6):

First thing, for me ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.**Tls12** worked instead of Ssl3.

Secondly, I had to send the Basic Auth request along with some data (form-urlencoded). Here is the complete sample which worked for me perfectly, after trying many solutions.

Disclaimer: The code below is a mixture of solutions found on this link and some other stackoverflow links, thanks for the useful information.

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        String username = "user_name";
        String password = "password";
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

        //Form Data
        var formData = "var1=val1&var2=val2";
        var encodedFormData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formData);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("THE_URL");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = encodedFormData.Length;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(encodedFormData, 0, encodedFormData.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: So thankful for this answer. Worked perfectly for me! Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 4):

Following code will solve json response if there Basic Authentication and Proxy implemented.Also IIS 7.5 Hosting Problm will resolve.

```
public string HttpGetByWebRequ(string uri, string username, string password)
{
//For Basic Authentication
    string authInfo = username + ":" + password;
    authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));

//For Proxy
    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://10.127.0.1:8080", true);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    request.Proxy = proxy;

    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    string strResponse = "";
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        strResponse= sr.ReadToEnd();

    }

    return strResponse;
}
```

Comment: Not working for me (neither utf-8 nor ISO-8859-1 nor default). Any suggestions what to check ?Please note -  It works when I do " webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserID, Password);"

Answer (score 2):

The spec can be read as "ISO-8859-1" or "undefined". Your choice. It's known that many servers use ISO-8859-1 (like it or not) and will fail when you send something else.

For more information and a proposal to fix the situation, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-reschke-basicauth-enc-latest.html

Answer (score 1):

The following construction was not working correctly for me:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
```

I have used `CredentialCache` instead:

```
CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache
{
    {
        new Uri($"http://{request.Host}/"), "Basic",
        new NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
    }
};
request.Credentials = credentialCache;
```

However, if you would like to add multiple basic auth credentials (for example if there is redirection that you are aware of) you can use following function that I have made:

```
private void SetNetworkCredential(Uri uriPrefix, string authType, NetworkCredential credential)
{
    if (request.Credentials == null)
    {
        request.Credentials = new CredentialCache();
    }

    if (request.Credentials.GetCredential(uriPrefix, authType) == null)
    {
        (request.Credentials as CredentialCache).Add(uriPrefix, authType, credential);
    }
}
```

I hope it will help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do a Http Basic Auth string in C#

```
string username = "user";
string password = "pass";            
var basicAuthBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($"{username}:{password}");
var authHeaderValue = $"Basic {System.Convert.ToBase64String(basicAuthBytes)}";
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason why the top answer and others wont work for you is because it is missing a critical line. (note many API manuals leave out this necessity)

```
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
```