# C# web request authentication not working, tried multiple methods none work

Tags: c#, http, authentication, web, request

I need some help from anyone that knows C#! I need to create a simple C# script that creates a web request and is able to sign in using HTTP authentication. I am testing the script on one of my websites that I put a password lock on (don't worry nothing confidential just password blocked for testing purposes):
www.alienauthoritythegame.com

Username and password: edward tester

I have found several solutions on how to do this (including here on StackOverflow) but none of them work. Each code/method I tried includes a comment above it for the method I tried. None of these work. When I try to get a response from the web page, I got a 401 everytime. Any help is appreciated.

```
http_username = "edward";
   http_password = "tester";
   http_authentication = 1;

   try
   {
       string url = "http://alienauthoritythegame.com";
       Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
       WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
       HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
       request.PreAuthenticate = true;

        // Set up the credentials
        if (http_authentication == 1)
        {

            // method 1: Doesn't work
            NetworkCredential myNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(http_username, http_password);
            CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
            myCredentialCache.Add(myUri, "Basic", myNetworkCredential);
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Credentials = myCredentialCache;

            // Method 2: doesn't work
            ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential( "edward", "tester", "http://alienauthoritythegame.com"); //I used my username and password here
            request.Credentials = credentials;

            // Method 3: doesn't work
            System.Net.NetworkCredential netCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("edward", "tester", "http://alienauthoritythegame.com");
            request.Credentials = netCredential;

            // Method 4: doesn't work
            string authInfo = http_username + ":" + http_password;
            authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

            // Method 5: doesn't work
            byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("edward" + ":" + "tester");
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);
        }

        // Creates a 401 every time
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
   }
   catch (Exception webEx)
   {
        Response.Write(webEx.ToString());
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334521/c-sharp-webrequest-authentication

Comment: Phil Wright, that article you are linking to, I did try that, look at my source code. It is one of many methods I tried and I CANNOT get past the 401 error... see method 5. I did not use a function but just put the base code there, that persons method is not working.

Comment: instead of using the UTF8Encoding, try....System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").

Comment: Plus, you might need to add the realm as part of the buffer. http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000581.html

Comment: Method 4 and 5 are kind of the same, one does use the 64 bit. I did check out that cook computing article you linked, that is interesting and sounds like the issue with the web page I am accessing. What is interesting, my site is hosted on GoDaddy, and even visiting it in a normal browser it makes me authenticate twice... looks like he is using some special framework in his code? XML RPC?