# Restful Webservice and C# - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone, slim

I've made a Restful `Webservice` with Slim. (See below).
As you can see there is a authentication.

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "users" => [
        "root" => "example",
        "user" => "example"
    ]
]));
$app->get('/example/:name', function($name){
    echo json_encode($name);
});
```

Now I tried to connect with `Windows Phone`. Without the authentication everything went fine. But I can't get it work with it.

Here is my code for `Windows Phone` so far:

```
Uri endpointUri = new Uri( "http://domain/example/check");
using ( HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    List<Example> c;

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpointUri);
    var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    c= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Example>>(jsonResponse);


    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(c[0].id);
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Phone needs to send username and password to Slim when doing a request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334521/c-sharp-webrequest-authentication

Comment: Slim didn't need that an 'authentication' be set in the http header ?

Comment: Basic auth credentials are passed in `Authorization` header, thus it is needed.