# Web request (GET) with Basic Auth and SSL failing

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest, basic-authentication

I have browsed through all questions in stackoverflow but I still cannot make my request working. The server (I have no access to it, so I do not know what is going on over there) is always responding with 403.

I was told that I have to use Basic Auth with HTTPS. At first I tried it with PostMan (Chrome add-on) and it worked perfectly. Fiddler says that PostMan has sent this request:

```
GET https://mypage.com/api/topic HTTP/1.1
Host: mypage.com
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36
Postman-Token: 7363b868-cc6e-1dff-d5d0-c7a0c1924fa7
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=imxY132456123Scai90Nrsv
```

I wanted to reproduce this in our C# application, but whatever I try I get a 403 answer from the server. This is (one) of the versions in C# I have tried:

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(Login, Password);
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add("mypage.com", 443, "Basic", nc);

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://mypage.com/api/topic");
request.Credentials = cc;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

That is what is sent according to Fiddler:

```
GET https://mypage.com/api/topic HTTP/1.1
Host: mypage.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Obviously there are some things missing. I am wondering which ones (like user-agent?) are really essential and I hope you can help me fix the problem.

Comment: the really important one is `Authorization`. it seems, even though you set  `request.Credentials` it is not being sent. check out this answer, it has an example of how to create credentials for ssl http://stackoverflow.com/a/4346843/278329 (its a  bit weird with the WebRequest i had some problems too in the past, just search StackOverflow until u find a method that generates a similar `Authorization` header. Also , you send a cookie with a SessionID, that might be very important (i cant tell though). the other headers are usually not checked by the server but it is possible

Comment: Thanks @x4rf41 for your input. The answer in that post also didn't work. I had to manually set the header. It never worked with the NetworkCredentials... But it led me to another post in stackoverflow that helped me solve the problem. Yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could swear that I have already tried setting headers exactly this way. Probably I have been stuck for too long and made a mistake...

So here is my solution:

```
string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Login + ":" + Password));

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mypage.com/api/topic");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
```

Thank god, it works now.