# Spreedly authentication error using C#.Net HttpWebRequest: "You must specify an environment_key parameter"

Tags: httpwebrequest, basic-authentication, system.net.httpwebrequest, spreedly

I'm currently working with Spreedly REST API which works with basic http authentication.

At first, I set my credentials this way:

```
webRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, password);
```

It worked well for many of the API resources including POSTing new gateways, GETing gateways, PUTing data on a gateway and even redacting a gateway.

I hit a wall when I tried to POST a new payment_method at their `/v1/payment_methods.<format>` resource.

The error I'm getting:

```
HTTP 422
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "key": "errors.environment_key_parameter_required",
      "message": "You must specify an environment_key parameter."
    }
  ]
}
```

After verifying a lot of things, I tried it using curl based on their examples and it worked.

The issue seems to be in the way I set my credentials in the HttpWebRequest even though it's the same code I use for the other working resources.

I tried using the CredentialCache because I could specify "Basic" and it failed the same way:

```
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(webRequest.RequestUri, "Basic", new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, password));
webRequest.Credentials = cache;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Here's what worked:

I created my own authorization HTTP header as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13956730/5869109 and it worked well:

```
String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
.GetBytes(user + ":" + password));
webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Comment: Would be great to know what's different with `webRequest.Credentials` compared to manually setting base64 encoded header. Nice one ;)