# Getting Unauthorized error on c# WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Tags: c#, api

Im getting anauthorized error when doing a GET request on C# but if I try it using post man its returns just fine.

heres my c# code:

```
url = @"http://somesource.com/api/v10/" + url;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token 3e68409924cc57ff07a8e29a18341fd99d3fba91ds");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Timeout = TimeO; 


      try { 
           WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
           status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription.ToString();


           if (status != "OK")
           Log.WriteLog(module, "Response x:: " + status);

          Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
          dataResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
          reader.Close();
          dataStream.Close();
          response.Close();
      } catch (WebException ex)
        {
          dataResponse = "{\"Error\":true,\"Update\":false,\"Msg\":\"RQ x:: " + ex.Message + "\"}";
          Log.WriteLog(module, dataResponse);
      }
```

it returns  `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

but when I try using the same url + header with `Authorization = "Token 3e68409924cc57ff07a8e29a18341fd99d3fba91ds"` on post man as GET request, it returns json data just fine.

although if I dont send the headers on postman i get

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

and if I intentionally set the token wrong, this is what I get:

```
{
    "detail": "Invalid token."
}
```

different from what the c# program logs. which is

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

what could be the reason for this?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) is recommended over the older `WebRequest` and related classes.

Comment: Yes @Herohtar, Ive read about it, but im not really c# programmer, i was just tasked to fix some previous programmers code, so I prefer not to re structure the program :D thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 1):

try the following code. original reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334521/httpwebrequest-using-basic-authentication)

```
string url = @"https://telematicoprova.agenziadogane.it/TelematicoServiziDiUtilitaWeb/ServiziDiUtilitaAutServlet?UC=22&SC=1&ST=2";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Credentials = GetCredential();
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;       

     private CredentialCache GetCredential()
        {
            string url = @"https://telematicoprova.agenziadogane.it/TelematicoServiziDiUtilitaWeb/ServiziDiUtilitaAutServlet?UC=22&SC=1&ST=2";
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
            credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ead_username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ead_password"]));
            return credentialCache;
        }
```

Comment: I think this method is not applicable for my situation, since the token is kinda static and was provided to us, we dont really need to login any more.  although I might find other options from the source :D thanks !

Comment: Please, remove this line: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`. Or explain what's for and when (if) should be used. Also, this is for `basic` auth, which doesn't apply here.