# HTTP basic authentication for 1fichier.com

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, authentication, httprequest, basic-authentication

I am trying to direct download some files using basic authentication from 1fichier.com, this works perfectly in browsers "https://email:password@1fichier.com/?file_ID&auth=1", but i am trying to do the same thing in my application and nothing is working... i tried request header with pure email and password, i tried header with base64 encoded email and password , i tried to send a Post request with my credentials but i always get 401 error : Unauthorized. Does Anyone Know how can i send authentication in my http request to 1fichier servers ?

This is what they provided in their Help page :

After login, a Premium member can download unlimited number of files, without limitations.
!!! You MUST login to be recognized as Premium !!!

You can also direct download using "basic authentication" :
https://email:password@1fichier.com/?file_ID
Tip: add
&auth=1
to the URL. The server will ask for an authentication.
'@' of the email address is invalid with this protocol and you must use '%' instead.

Wget example :
wget 'download link' --no-check-certificate --http-user='email' --http-password='password' --auth-no-challenge --content-disposition

```
     using UnityEngine.Networking;

     string user = "my email";
     string password = "my password";
     string combined = user + ":" + password;
     
     UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://1fichier.com/?cs6czd22c8odod74dal2&auth=1");
     request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic " + combined);
     yield return request.SendWebRequest();
     if(request.isHttpError)
     {
       Debug.Log(request.error);
     }
      else
     {
         if (request.isDone)
         {
             Debug.Log("Done");
         }
     }
```

The base64 encoded :

```
     using UnityEngine.Networking;

     string user = "my email";
     string password = "my password";
     string base64User = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user));
     string base64pass = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
     string combined = base64User + ":" + base64pass;
     UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://1fichier.com/?cs6czd22c8odod74dal2&auth=1");
     request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic " + combined);
     yield return request.SendWebRequest();
     if(request.isHttpError)
     {
         Debug.Log(request.error);
     }
     else
     {
         if (request.isDone)
         {
             Debug.Log("Done");
         }
     }
```

Comment: Show us the code you've tried

Comment: Because of the lack of code, hard to tell if this is related or duplicated of other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334521/httpwebrequest-using-basic-authentication)

Comment: look into their api documentation. 401 is an authorization issue and this should be covered by their docs.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). as a first pointer: if you want help ***debugging your code*** -  how do you think this to be possible without you ***showing us your code***?

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?  Https uses TLS for authentication.  You are getting an authentication error due to TLS failing or not using HTTPS which is more likely.

Answer (score 1):

I Found What i am looking for, it didn't have anything to do with the request header;

the original url that i pasted in the browser is like this :
"https://myemail@gmail.com:mypassword@1fichier.com/?File_ID&auth=1";

so i recorder the browser's web request and the url came out like this :
"https://myemail%40gmail.com:mypassword@1fichier.com/?File_ID&auth=1";

i pasted this in my application in the get request as a url and it worked perfecly.

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;
UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://myemail%40gmail.com:mypassword@1fichier.com/?File_ID&auth=1");
```